# GridBagLayout 2 JPanels - One less width than other

Tags: java, swing, layout, jpanel, gridbaglayout

I would like to find out how exactly would I go about to having two JPanels on one JPanel, all using GridBagLayout.

Basically you have your Top Most JPanel and then with 2 JPanels on their as below requirement:

```
--------------------------------------
|                          |         |
|                          |         |
|                          |         |
|     JPanel 1             | JPanel  |
|                          |    2    |
|                          |         |
|                          |         |
--------------------------------------
```

Basically I would need JPanel 1 to be bigger than JPanel 2. But also JPanel 2 must NOT resize, JPanel 1 should only resize if the main panel gets resized.

Any idea's?

Comment: Sounds like you would be better off with `BorderLayout`. Put your JPanel 1 in the `CENTER` and the JPanel 2 in the `EAST`.

Comment: Tried that. JPanel 1 does not re-size, but JPanel 2 re-sizes... Below example works perfectly with my added comment.

Comment: That's simply not possible. If JPanel 1 is in the center, it will take the extra vertical space and horizontal space, while the one in the east will only resize vertically, never horizontally.

Comment: Ah yes sorry, I just remembered now, i set the first panel to LINE_START and the second panel to CENTER, which then made the second panel resized

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at this code example and see if this is what you wanted :

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.Random;
import javax.swing.*;

public class GridBagExample {
    private JPanel leftPanel;
    private JPanel rightPanel;

    private GridBagConstraints gbc;
    private Random random;

    public GridBagExample() {
        gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.FIRST_LINE_START;
        gbc.insets = new Insets(5, 5, 5, 5);

        random = new Random();
    }

    private void displayGUI() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Swing Worker Example");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);

        JPanel contentPane = getPanel();
        contentPane.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        leftPanel = getPanel();
        rightPanel = getPanel();

        addComp(contentPane, leftPanel, 0, 0, 1, 1,
                    GridBagConstraints.BOTH, 0.7, 1.0);
        addComp(contentPane, rightPanel, 1, 0, 1, 1,
                    GridBagConstraints.BOTH, 0.3, 1.0);

        frame.setContentPane(contentPane);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private void addComp(JPanel panel, JComponent comp, int gridx,
                            int gridy, int gridwidth, int gridheight,
                                int fill, double weightx, double weighty) {
        gbc.gridx = gridx;
        gbc.gridy = gridy;
        gbc.gridwidth = gridwidth;
        gbc.gridheight = gridheight;
        gbc.fill = fill;
        gbc.weightx = weightx;
        gbc.weighty = weighty;

        panel.add(comp, gbc);
    }

    private JPanel getPanel() {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setOpaque(true);
        panel.setBackground(new Color(random.nextInt(256),
                            random.nextInt(256), random.nextInt(256)));

        return panel;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new GridBagExample().displayGUI();
            }
        };
        EventQueue.invokeLater(runnable);
    }
}
```

Though if you want your right `JPanel` not to change size, you can pass `GridBagConstraints.NONE` to the function instead of `GridBagConstraints.BOTH` as done by me. Since without the actual contents known for this `JPanel` which will become its part, its hard to present its true size.

OUTPUT :

[image: GridBagLayoutExample]

## EDIT :

Updating my code, to better explain, as to what I am saying, though I used **user2699405**'s (OP) ideas too from the comments.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.Random;
import javax.swing.*;

public class GridBagExample {
    private JPanel leftPanel;
    private JPanel rightPanel;

    private GridBagConstraints gbc;
    private Random random;

    public GridBagExample() {
        gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.FIRST_LINE_START;
        gbc.insets = new Insets(5, 5, 5, 5);

        random = new Random();
    }

    private void displayGUI() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Swing Worker Example");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);

        JPanel contentPane = getPanel();
        contentPane.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        leftPanel = getPanel();
        rightPanel = new JPanel() {
            @Override
            public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
                return (new Dimension(100, 100));
            }
        };

        addComp(contentPane, leftPanel, 0, 0, 1, 1,
                    GridBagConstraints.BOTH, 1.0, 1.0);
        addComp(contentPane, rightPanel, 1, 0, 1, 1,
                    GridBagConstraints.NONE, 0.0, 1.0);

        frame.setContentPane(contentPane);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private void addComp(JPanel panel, JComponent comp, int gridx,
                            int gridy, int gridwidth, int gridheight,
                                int fill, double weightx, double weighty) {
        gbc.gridx = gridx;
        gbc.gridy = gridy;
        gbc.gridwidth = gridwidth;
        gbc.gridheight = gridheight;
        gbc.fill = fill;
        gbc.weightx = weightx;
        gbc.weighty = weighty;

        panel.add(comp, gbc);
    }

    private JPanel getPanel() {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setOpaque(true);
        panel.setBackground(new Color(random.nextInt(256),
                            random.nextInt(256), random.nextInt(256)));

        return panel;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new GridBagExample().displayGUI();
            }
        };
        EventQueue.invokeLater(runnable);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I just modified a little bit as well. As said the second panel should not re-size, the weightx of 0.3 still makes it re-sizable. Changed that to 0, then i set minimum and preferred size on the second panel to make it show the second panel. Now when you re-size, it only makes the left panel bigger and right panel stays as is. If you don't set minimum and preferred size then the 2nd panel won't show.

Comment: @user2699405 : I hope though, that the second `JPanel` in question, should be `VERTICALLY` aligned with the first one, or you do not even want that to happen also !!! Though I prefer overriding `getPreferredSize()` of a `JComponent` instead of explicitly calling `setPreferredSize()` on the same, since the former works in every situation, though latter might won't work in some :-)

Comment: Yes as per the picture posted that is precisely as it should look like. The blue side above (second panel) should never resize which is the requirement.

Comment: @user2699405 : I guess then this updated code will help, though you can override `getMinimumSize()` too to return the same values (or your own set of values) as done by `getPreferredSize()` :-)

Comment: +1 previoulsy, but really isn't possible to stop resize in one of two resize coordinates (to simulating BorderLayout)

Comment: @mKorbel : Exactly, that's what I thought too, since the behaviour as specified by the OP, can easily be attained with `BorderLayout`, without using `GridBagLayout`. Though the requirement thingy just confused me, a bit :-)

Comment: GBC is proportional LayoutManager, I don't know how to stop of resize only one of two directions